# How to disable/hide the W1032 warning ? (Exported package threadvar %s cannot be used outside of this package)

Tags: delphi, delphi-11-alexandria

I would like to disable/remove entirely that warning, because my package is a whole RAD Server module, so those threadvars will never have the chance to be used outside the package.

I have tried {$WARNINGS OFF} on the threadvar definition, but it doesn't remove the warning.

```
unit CustomSession;

interface

uses
  System.Classes,
  System.SysUtils,
  EMS.ResourceAPI;

type
  TKpSession = record
    UserId: string;
    UserName: string;
    SessionToken: string;
    class procedure ValidateRequest(const AContext: TEndpointContext); static;
  end;

{$WARNINGS OFF}
threadvar
  KpSession: TKpSession;
{$WARNINGS ON}

resourcestring
  rsNotLoggedIn = 'You need to be logged in to access %s - %s';

implementation

uses
  CustomLocalize;

class procedure TKpSession.ValidateRequest(const AContext: TEndpointContext);
var
  UserId, Resource, Endpoint: string;
begin
  Resource := AContext.Request.Resource;
  Endpoint := AContext.EndpointName;
  if Assigned(AContext.User) then
    UserId := AContext.User.UserName;

  if UserId.Trim <> '' then
  begin
   KpSession.UserId := UserId;
   KpSession.UserName := UserId; // Retrieve username from the DDBB ?
   KpSession.SessionToken := AContext.User.SessionToken;
   // to-do: Check Permissions for the User on this Request/Endpoint.
  end
  else
  begin
    raise Exception.CreateFmt(_(rsNotLoggedIn), [Resource, Endpoint]);
  end;
end;

end.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put this line somewhere at the top of that unit:

```
{$WARN PACKAGED_THREADVAR OFF}
```